# Building user area and site admin - Django - CMS

Tags: django, django-admin, django-cms

I am a begginer with Django. I read a book and then I practiced building a real estate project which is working fine. Now I am going to create the admin area, for example, for the site editor to post articles, set posts as paid, edit layout texts ...

I used Django 1.9.10 to build the project. I have been reading and looks like I will need do use Django CSM. Do I have to start a new project or is it possible to change my Django project using django cms?

Thank you

Comment: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/install.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the built-in Admin module for that part?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/#explore-the-free-admin-functionality